# Stack consumption issue related to sequential calls

Tags: c, callstack, method-call

I've got a stack consumption issue with my C code and I cannot figure out exactly what's going on. The issue has started to trigg stack overflow crashes (not related to recursion that isn't used in my program). I suspect it is because:
- all of my functions take at least one home made debug interface (a structure I use to ease debugging) which is quite large (~1 or 2kB)
- some of my functions (for example one that implements an initalization sequence for some hardware) are too long (i.e. make too much sub-function calls)

Note: my C code is used in several applications, some being compiled with gcc, some with visual studio 2010, some with a C++ top layer. All suffer from this high stack usage issue.

I've made the following simple test code in order to demonstrate the problem:

```
typedef struct tDbgIf2 {
   int               verbose                          ;                                         // verbose level (0:no verbose)
   int               callLevel                        ;                                         // context depth in function call
   char              lhd[1024]                        ;                                         // configurable line header for log formating
} tDbgIf;                                                                                       // function debug interface

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tDbgIf mfunc(tDbgIf i) {
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   tDbgIf   v = i;

   v.verbose++;

   return v;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tDbgIf test1call(tDbgIf i) {
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   tDbgIf   v = i;

   v = mfunc(v);

   return v;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tDbgIf test2call(tDbgIf i) {
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   tDbgIf   v = i;

   v = mfunc(v);
   v = mfunc(v);

   return v;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tDbgIf test(tDbgIf i) {
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   tDbgIf   v = i;

   v           = test1call(v);
   v           = test2call(v);

   return v;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   tDbgIf   v;

   v           = test(v);

   return 0;
}
```

Using gcc 4.7.2 (MinGW on XP) with option -fstack-usage gives the follwing strange result:

```
cmd=gcc -fstack-usage -S test.c -o test.exe
test.c:8:8:mfunc        1060    static     
test.c:18:8:test1call   2100    static     
test.c:28:8:test2call   3164    static     
test.c:39:8:test        3168    static     
test.c:50:5:main        2128    static
```

If I understand correctly:
- main stack usage < test stack usage => the statistics are not cumulative
- gcc considers that test2call needs more stack than test1call, despite those two function have the same iput/output parameters + local variables

I can't understand why is this ? It would suggest that: **(1) stack usage of a function would be proportional to the number of sub-call it makes**
(1) seems strange to me because it would imply that in the real life, function size (in the sense of how much sub-call it makes) would be limited by stack availability. I've never heard about such a limitation (unlike the recursion depth limitation for example which is well explained on Internet). And even more, I've always thought that stack state should be restored at all (sub-)call return.

The generated assembly looks like:

```
...
_test:                             - start of test
LFB3:                              - 
    .cfi_startproc                   - 
    pushl   %ebp                       - return context saved
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8            - 
    .cfi_offset 5, -8                - 
    movl    %esp, %ebp                 - new context activated   
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5          - 
    pushl   %edi                       - 
    pushl   %esi                       - 
    pushl   %ebx                       - 
    subl    $3148, %esp                - stack static alloc (for test)
    .cfi_offset 7, -12               - 
    .cfi_offset 6, -16               - 
    .cfi_offset 3, -20               - 
    leal    -1056(%ebp), %edx          - v <- i (not sure)
    leal    12(%ebp), %ebx             - v <- i (not sure)
    movl    $258, %eax                 - v <- i (not sure)
    movl    %edx, %edi                 - v <- i (not sure)
    movl    %ebx, %esi                 - v <- i (not sure)
    movl    %eax, %ecx                 - v <- i (not sure)
    rep movsl                        - ???
    leal    -1056(%ebp), %eax          - ???
    movl    %eax, -2108(%ebp)          - ???
    leal    4(%esp), %edx              - ???
    leal    -1056(%ebp), %ebx          - ???
    movl    $258, %eax                 - ???
    movl    %edx, %edi                 - ???
    movl    %ebx, %esi                 - ???
    movl    %eax, %ecx                 - ???
    rep movsl                        - 
    movl    -2108(%ebp), %eax          - 
    movl    %eax, (%esp)               - 
    call    _test1call                 - sub call
    leal    -2104(%ebp), %eax          - v <- ans (not sure)
    movl    %eax, -2112(%ebp)          - v <- ans (not sure)
    leal    4(%esp), %edx              - v <- ans (not sure)
    leal    -1056(%ebp), %ebx          - v <- ans (not sure)
    movl    $258, %eax                 - v <- ans (not sure)
    movl    %edx, %edi                 - v <- ans (not sure)
    movl    %ebx, %esi                 - v <- ans (not sure)
    movl    %eax, %ecx                 - v <- ans (not sure)
    rep movsl                        - 
    movl    -2112(%ebp), %eax          - 
    movl    %eax, (%esp)               - 
    call    _test2call                 - sub call
    leal    -1056(%ebp), %edx          - v <- ans (not sure)
    leal    -2104(%ebp), %ebx          - v <- ans (not sure)
    movl    $258, %eax                 - v <- ans (not sure)
    movl    %edx, %edi                 - v <- ans (not sure)
    movl    %ebx, %esi                 - v <- ans (not sure)
    movl    %eax, %ecx                 - v <- ans (not sure)
    rep movsl                        - ans <- v (not sure)
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax              - ans <- v (not sure)
    movl    %eax, %edx                 - ans <- v (not sure)
    leal    -1056(%ebp), %ebx          - ans <- v (not sure)
    movl    $258, %eax                 - ans <- v (not sure)
    movl    %edx, %edi                 - ans <- v (not sure)
    movl    %ebx, %esi                 - ans <- v (not sure)
    movl    %eax, %ecx                 - ans <- v (not sure)
    rep movsl                        -
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax              -
    addl    $3148, %esp                - stack released
    popl    %ebx                       -
    .cfi_restore 3                   -
    popl    %esi                       -
    .cfi_restore 6                   -
    popl    %edi                       -
    .cfi_restore 7                   -
    popl    %ebp                       - context restored
    .cfi_restore 5                   -
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4                -
    ret                              -
    .cfi_endproc                     -
LFE3:
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .globl  _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
...
```

If I understand correctly:
- the stack is not immediatly cleared after a sub-call return
- (1) is true (at least with default gcc/visual studio otpimization options)

Could someone confirm ?

Comment: this seems to work without any errors.

Comment: To check whether there is really any memory leak/stack overflow, try using `valgrind`.

Comment: Just a guess: since in C the caller clears up the stack, I suspect that in testcall2 gcc tries to save one clear up. It could do so by omitting one clear up (adding the amount of space occupied by the activation frame to SP) after the first call to mfunc, and adding twice that number to SP after the second call. In fact, if there is such optimisation your code (being tiny) would never clear up the stack, consecutive calls would just add new activation records and the whole lot would be cleared up at the exit from main. You could check the generated assembly at different opt levels.

Comment: @perreal Hi perreal. You're right. It perfectly compiles and runs without any error because it is only an illustration of the problem. It tries to demonstrate that a function stack usage will grow with the number of sub-call made inside of it which is something strange to me and also annoying because it leads to limitations in the number of sequential sub-calls that can be made in a function. In my actual C/C++ program (that is much more complex and that I cannot share) my initialization function make hundreds of sequential sub-calls to functions with big (in size) parameters.

Comment: @dfract, but if the minimal working example you provide is not able to reproduce the real problem, then it is really useless.

Comment: @Don't You Worry Child - Hi Don't You Worry Child. Thanks for the advice. I've already eard about valgrind but never used it. I'll have a look. What I know is that my problem is for sure a stack overflow (the exception is properly catched in my program. I've also made a lot of dump analyzes using WinDbg), not related to recursion.

Comment: @user1666959 - Hi user1666959. Your scenario matches with my observations: testXcall stack usage will grow with X (the number of sub-calls). Whatever is the stack quantity required by testXcall, the whole of it is cleared at testXcall return (no stack leak).

Comment: @user1666959. I've followed your advise and get interesting results:

Comment: cmd=gcc -pass-exit-codes -fstack-usage **-O0** test.c -o test.exe  
test.c:8:8:mfunc        36      static  
test.c:18:8:test1call   **56**      static  
test.c:28:8:test2call   **96**      static  
test.c:39:5:main        96      static

Comment: cmd=gcc -pass-exit-codes -fstack-usage **-O1** test.c -o test.exe  
test.c:8:8:mfunc        4       static  
test.c:18:8:test1call   **32**      static  
test.c:28:8:test2call   **64**      static  
test.c:39:5:main        96      static

Comment: cmd=gcc -pass-exit-codes -fstack-usage **-O2** test.c -o test.exe  
test.c:8:8:mfunc        4       static  
test.c:18:8:test1call   **4**       static  
test.c:28:8:test2call   **4**       static  
test.c:39:5:main        16      static

Comment: You may also want to check if the manual says something about the statistics being cumulative...which is useful if all you care about how much is the peak stack usage (ie at the deepest nested call, for an embedded system thats paramount)...the decrease in stack consumption could just be because at higher optimisation levels more of the arguments are passed in registers so they dont take up stack space. That technique has its limits though. To get back to the original question: is this just curiosity now or is there a problem?

Comment: @user1666959. Hi. As far as I understand the gcc manual (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options, section -fstack-usage) and according to my observations (I've seen functions communing less stack than some of its sub-functions), those statistics are not cumulative.

Comment: @user1666959. What I find interesting with those results obtained at different optim levels is not really the decrease of stack consumption but the fact that upon a certain level (2), test1call and test2call consumption are equal (Which is what I was expecting at any optim level as those two functions have the same arguments + local variable)

Comment: @user1666959. Actually, I've managed to make my program viable by optimizing stack usage using general techniques like moving big buffers to the heap when possible. I'd like to save extra stack because I known the margin is small and there is a high risk to face stack overflow crashes again as soon as I will want to update my program (I use Windows default stack size of 1MB). According to my investigations, **(1) : stack usage of a function would be proportional to the number of sub-call it makes**.

Comment: I was really not expecting this behaviour. It would mean that in the real life, function size (in the sense of how much sub-call it makes) would be limited by stack availability. I've never heard about such a limitation (unlike the recursion depth limitation for example which is well explained on Internet). On the opposite, I've always thought that stack state should be restored at all (sub-)call return. Finally I'm interesting in understanding details of the story as most of the stack consummed in my program could be saved by overcoming (1).

Comment: Odd: I cant reproduce your problem:

Answer (score 0):

Need to switch to answer for lack of space. I cant reproduce the behaviour you are describing except for -O0 (cygwin on XP gcc 4.8.2):

```
-O0
sc.c:8:8:mfunc  24      static
sc.c:18:8:test1call     40      static
sc.c:28:8:test2call     64      static
sc.c:39:5:main  80      dynamic,bounded
-O1
sc.c:8:8:mfunc  4       static
sc.c:18:8:test1call     4       static
sc.c:28:8:test2call     4       static
sc.c:39:5:main  80      dynamic,bounded
-O2
sc.c:8:8:mfunc  4       static
sc.c:18:8:test1call     4       static
sc.c:28:8:test2call     4       static
sc.c:39:5:main  16      static
-O3
sc.c:8:8:mfunc  4       static
sc.c:18:8:test1call     4       static
sc.c:28:8:test2call     4       static
sc.c:39:5:main  16      static
```

As to '(1) : stack usage of a function would be proportional to the number of sub-call it makes'. I'd be shocked if that was true. Nested calls foo(x){ f(g(h(x)));} increase the level (in the activation tree) so the stack must (well, almost true) grow, but in sequential calls foo(x) { f(x); g(x); h(x); } the stack is reused. The standard activation/return sequence (Aho, Lam, Sethi, Ullman: Compilers Chp 7.2) is actually very small, if you run out of 1M stack in non-recursive calls you must be having (a) large number of local variables, or (b) extremely long argument lists, or (c) you are using a C++ compiler which allocates temporary objects on the stack.

'On the opposite, I've always thought that stack state should be restored at all (sub-)call return'. In C the caller clear up the stack.

I guess (1) you are either on some strange (for me) architecture or (2) you have some unusual compiler options set (CFLAGS?).

Your best bet is 'gcc -S' and examine the assembly output.

Comment: Hi user1666959. You're right on (a), (b) not on (c) and (1) and (2) (I use gcc on XP/i7 without CFLAGS option). Thanks for the precision about stack being cleared by caller rather than callee (I've got the feeling it is a key detail in this story). Thanks also for the gcc -S switch (I didn't knwo this and was looking for a way to look at assembly). I've used it and modified my question in order to summerize (or try to) what I know now.